# Remove generated string from Mongoose schema with custom validation

Tags: node.js, mongoose, schema

I have a schema with a custom validation.

```js
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        validate: {
            validator: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{3,16}$/, 
            message: "Usernames must be 3 to 16 characters long and contain only alphanumeric characters and underscores (_)."
        },
    },
    // ...other things
});
```

However, the validation message comes out like this when I type an invalid username:

```
User validation failed: username: Usernames must be 3 to 16 characters long and contain only alphanumeric characters and underscores (_).
```

How do I get rid of the part of the string at the start that says `User validation failed: username:` ?

Answer (score 1):

The format is embedded into the [`ValidationError` class](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/2a3d9fd25c075f348cebf927af91ed5c22c37599/lib/error/validation.js#L23-L56). Short of monkey patching that class, I can't see a way to easily change the format.

One option could be to run validation before being thrown by the model:

```
const user = new User({ username: 'ab' })
const error = user.validateSync()
console.log(error.errors['username'].message)
```

Or handle `ValidationError` when caught:

```
try {
  const user = new User({ username: 'ab' })
  await user.save()
} catch (error) {
  if (error instanceOf mongoose.Document.ValidationError ) {
    console.log(error.errors['username'].message)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the initial string , you could simply use a split method on the string returned before displaying it. Here is a sample code:

```
let stringa = "User validation failed: username: Usernames must be 3 to 16 characters long and contain only alphanumeric characters and underscores (_)."; //replace this with error message
let stringb = (stringa.split(":")[2]);

console.log(stringb);//This displays the needed output string with Usernames
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error object has another nested object called properties that has a field called message.
(example: `properties.message`) This gives you the exact string you wrote in the mongoose schema